# Rotate image using matrix around center of 'imageview'

Tags: android, image, matrix, bitmap

This is my code

```
//originBitmap is bitmap in imageview
setMatrix(originBitmap.getWidth()/2,originBitmap.getHeight()/2);

void setMatrix(float x,float y){ 
    matrix.setTranslate(matrixX,matrixY);
    matrix.preRotate(matrixR,x,y);
    matrix.preScale(matrixS,matrixS,x,y);

    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

My code is work currectly in this situation. [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0x3T.jpg)(blue=imageview, red=bitmap image)

But when this situation, [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hupLt.jpg) image rotate around it's center, so users see strange image what moves around strange position.

How can I rotate image around imageview's center position?

Comment: where do you define `matrix`? (the one inside `imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);`)

Comment: This is major part of code. Original code is so long and has any relationship.